# Array variables and constructors - why my code no work?

Tags: java

I am just messing around and this doesn't work.

Wow. I don't understand so much stuff. Why is this broken ?

In the main program when I make the class I want to pass two arrays into it.

```
*/
public class sortarray {

    int [] A ;
     int [] B;

     int [] a;
     int[] b;

 public sortarray(A[],B[]){
    this.a = A[];
    this.b = B[];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should visit some basic tutorial site first. This doesn't seem like java code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong. It should be :

```
    public sortarray(int[] A,int[] B)
    {
      this.a = A;
      this.b = B;
    }
```

And I'm not sure why you have both a & b and A & B arrays as members in your class.

Comment: Because I want to sort them then do stuff to them. You're right I don't need the other A and B. I thought I did.